# How to display a text in the impact point position

Tags: unity

In my 3d game, i would like to display a text 'near' the impact point of a bullet. 
I think i'm having problems setting properly text position. 
This is my code.
The script is attached to an object Canvas.
position is the Vector3 impact position.

```
GameObject obj = new GameObject ();
Text _text = obj.AddComponent<Text> ();

_text.transform.position = position;
_text.text = message;
_text.fontSize = startSize;
_text.color = color;
```

I'm pretty sure i've to convert from a world space to a 'user interface' space.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

`_text.transform.position = camera.WorldToScreenPoint(position);`

You'd need to get a reference to the camera first. See [an example from the docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.WorldToScreenPoint.html)